# Is magnetic field strength (Teslas) inversely proportional to distance from the magnet squared?

Tags: magnetic-fields

I can't find a solid answer on this, I've read that magnetic force is inversely proportional to distance squared so does that mean it's strength is too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have to define what source system you're talking about.

Also, that sort of result usually implies that the system on which the force is applied is point-like, or at least very small. So it's more correct to speak about the field radiated by the source, without mentioning that system.

Even for the electric field, saying that it's proportional to the inverse square of the distance isn't always true. It is, however, the case for the very important, most basic example, the point-like charge (see Coulomb force).

But there's no point-like "magnetic charge", so you don't have that as a reference. The next simplest example is arguably the magnetic dipole. The decrease of its field with the distance varies noticeably, depending on the situation (constant magnetic moment or not, near field or far field, and so on).

The Biot and Savard formula shows however than an "element of electrical current" does generate a magnetic field, the latter follows the inverse square law. But be careful, since that law is only valid in magneto*static* (and approximately valid for slowly varying currents).